# Alternative to desktop for file storage or how can I enable storing files on the desktop?

Tags: desktop, files

While it makes a lot of sense to me that launcher icons are hidden from the desktop because of the easy app menu access, I think that I will greatly miss being able to store files on the desktop temporarily for ease of access.

> Is there a way to get this functionality back or is there a sensible
>   alternative for temporary file storage with quick access?